# Decrypt encrpyted shell script

Tags: shell, unix, aix

when I was trying to look what was written in shell script, it came all in binary.

So I wrote this command and it gave me this output.

```
file xyz.sh
```

and it gave me error `executable (RISC System/6000) or object module not stripped`

my Unix environment is AIX and korn shell.

How can vie what is written in shell script.

Comment: that isn't an error. `file` command tells you what type of file it is depending upon 1st few bytes of the file(magic number). which in your case it says it is `executable (RISC System/6000) or object module not stripped`. If the file is indeed an `sh` script, it should show `scriptname: POSIX shell script, ASCII text executable`

Comment: How can I view it, as it is in complete binary ?

Comment: Sadly, binary executables cannot be converted into source program (or some script language program).

Comment: Perhaps you can find the source code on Internet or find documentation explaining what you want to know about the program. It is silly indeed dat the filename ends with `.sh`.